# Insert multiple rows in one table based on number in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, generate-series

I am creating a database for the first time using Postgres 9.3 on MacOSX.

Let's say I have table `A` and `B`. `A` starts off as empty and `B` as filled. I would like the number of entries in column `all_names` in table `B` to equal the `number` for each `names` in table `A` like table `B` below. Thus `names` should contain each unique entry from `all_names` and `number` its count. I am not used to the syntax, yet, so I do not really know how to go about it. The `birthday` column is redundant.

Table **`A`**

```
names | number
------+--------
Carl  | 3
Bill  | 4
Jen   | 2
```

Table **`B`**

```
 all_names | birthday
-----------+------------
Carl       | 17/03/1980
Carl       | 22/08/1994
Carl       | 04/09/1951
Bill       | 02/12/2003
Bill       | 11/03/1975
Bill       | 04/06/1986
Bill       | 08/07/2005
Jen        | 05/03/2009
Jen        | 01/04/1945
```

Would this be the correct way to go about it?

```
insert into a (names, number)
select b.all_names, count(b.all_names)
from b
group by b.all_names;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer to original question

Postgres allows set-returning functions (SRF) to multiply rows. [**`generate_series()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) is your friend:

```
INSERT INTO b (all_names, birthday)
SELECT names, current_date -- AS birthday ??
FROM  (SELECT names, generate_series(1, number) FROM a);
```

Since the introduction of [**`LATERAL` in Postgres 9.3**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) you can do stick to standard SQL: the SRF moves from the `SELECT` to the `FROM` list:

```
INSERT INTO b (all_names, birthday)
SELECT a.names, current_date -- AS birthday ??
FROM   a, generate_series(1, a.number) AS rn
```

`LATERAL` is implicit here, as explained [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html):

> `LATERAL` can also precede a function-call `FROM` item, but in this case
>   it is a noise word, because the function expression can refer to
>   earlier FROM items in any case.

#### Reverse operation

The above is the reverse operation (approximately) of a simple [aggregate `count()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
INSERT INTO a (name, number)
SELECT all_names, count(*)
FROM   b
GROUP  BY 1;
```

... which fits your updated question.

Note a subtle difference between `count(*)` and `count(all_names)`. The former counts all rows, no matter what, while the latter only counts rows where `all_names IS NOT NULL`. If your column `all_names` is defined as `NOT NULL`, both return the same, but `count(*)` is a bit shorter and faster.

About `GROUP  BY 1`:

- [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)

Comment: `create table b (names text, number int);` `insert into b (names) values ('bill'), ('bill'), ('jen');` `select b.names from b, generate_series(1, b.number) as rn;` Why isn't this working? Thanks.

Comment: @jO.: In your example, `number` is NULL. So `generate_series()` is not going to generate any rows. Insert values for `number`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. I have updated my question. I realized it might not have been clear enough what I was after, even thought your answer worked for me the first time around - oddly enough since `generate_series()` wont work with NULL. I must have entered the data wrongly. Many thanks!

Comment: @jO.: Basically you are after the inverse operation and your solution should work. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: THANKS! Really appreciate your help and clarification!