# GROUP BY + CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case, aggregate-functions

I have a working query that is grouping data by hardware model and a result, but the problem is there are many *"results"*.  I have tried to reduce that down to *"if result = 0  then keep as 0, else set it to 1"*.  This generally works, but I end up having:

```
    day     |      name      | type | case | count
------------+----------------+------+------+-------
 2013-11-06 | modelA         |    1 |    0 |   972
 2013-11-06 | modelA         |    1 |    1 |    42
 2013-11-06 | modelA         |    1 |    1 |     2
 2013-11-06 | modelA         |    1 |    1 |    11
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    1 |    0 |   456
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    1 |    1 |    16
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    1 |    1 |     8
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    3 |    0 | 21518
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    3 |    1 |     5
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    3 |    1 |     7
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    3 |    1 |   563
```

Instead of the aggregate I am trying to achieve, where only 1 row per type/case combo.

```
    day     |      name      | type | case | count
------------+----------------+------+------+-------
 2013-11-06 | modelA         |    1 |    0 |   972
 2013-11-06 | modelA         |    1 |    1 |    55
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    1 |    0 |   456
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    1 |    1 |    24
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    3 |    0 | 21518
 2013-11-06 | modelB         |    3 |    1 |   575
```

Here is my query:

```
select CURRENT_DATE-1 AS day, model.name, attempt.type, 
       CASE WHEN attempt.result = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
       count(*) 
from attempt attempt, prod_hw_id prod_hw_id, model model
where time >= '2013-11-06 00:00:00'  
AND time < '2013-11-07 00:00:00'
AND attempt.hard_id = prod_hw_id.hard_id
AND prod_hw_id.model_id = model.model_id
group by model.name, attempt.type, attempt.result
order by model.name, attempt.type, attempt.result;
```

Any tips on how I can achieve this would be awesome.

Day will always be defined in the `WHERE` clause, so it will not vary. `name, type, result(case)` and `count` will vary. In short, for any given model I want only 1 row per *"type + case"* combo. As you can see in the first result set I have 3 rows for `modelA` that have `type=1` and `case=1` (because there are many *"result"* values that I have turned into *0=0 and anything else=1*). I want that to be represented as 1 row with the count aggregated as in example data set 2.

Comment: *Which* row per type/case. Define your pick. Can day and name vary?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, for 1 model(name), only 1 row per type/result(case) combo.  there are many models.

Comment: There will always be at least 1 row for each model, but likely more than that because of succ/fail and different type.  I will add a bit more to the data set example.  Perhaps that would be more helpful.  I am trying to group by model, type, case; yes.  Generally it works, but I just wanted to aggregate the count on (otherwise) unique rows where only the count is different.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Your query would work already - except that you are running into naming conflicts or just confusing the **output column** (the `CASE` expression) with **source column** `result`, which has different content.

```
...
GROUP BY model.name, attempt.type, attempt.result
...
```

You need to `GROUP BY` your `CASE` expression instead of your source column:

```
...
GROUP BY model.name, attempt.type
       , CASE WHEN attempt.result = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
...
```

Or provide a **column alias** that's different from any column name in the `FROM` list - or else that column takes precedence:

```
SELECT ...
     , CASE WHEN attempt.result = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS result1
...
GROUP BY model.name, attempt.type, result1
...
```

The SQL standard is rather peculiar in this respect. [Quoting the manual here:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
> `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses;
> there you must write out the expression instead.

And:

> If an `ORDER BY` expression is a simple name that matches both an output
> column name and an input column name, `ORDER BY` will interpret it as
> the output column name. **This is the opposite of the choice that `GROUP BY`
> will make** in the same situation. This inconsistency is made to be
> compatible with the SQL standard.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

These conflicts can be avoided by using **positional references** (ordinal numbers) in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, referencing items in the `SELECT` list from left to right. See solution below.
The drawback is that this may be harder to read and vulnerable to edits in the `SELECT` list: one might forget to adapt positional references accordingly.

But you do *not* have to add the  column `day` to the `GROUP BY` clause, as long as it holds a constant value (`CURRENT_DATE-1`).

Rewritten and simplified with proper JOIN syntax and positional references it could look like this:

```
SELECT m.name
     , a.type
     , CASE WHEN a.result = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS result
     , CURRENT_DATE - 1 AS day
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM   attempt    a
JOIN   prod_hw_id p USING (hard_id)
JOIN   model      m USING (model_id)
WHERE  ts >= '2013-11-06 00:00:00'  
AND    ts <  '2013-11-07 00:00:00'
GROUP  BY 1,2,3
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

I avoided the column name `time`. That's a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and should not be used as identifier. Besides, your "time" obviously is a [`timestamp` or `date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), so that was rather misleading.

Comment: You should probably mention the option of using positional (numeric) column references while you're talking about naming conflicts, rather than just using an example that doesn't match the prose advice to that point. I still find that syntax much less readable myself, but I know some prefer it.

Comment: Very well explained otherwise, by the way; good work quoting the manual (and thus indirectly referencing the standard) for when and how you can use output column names.

Comment: @IMSoP: Hmm .. but I do mention positional parameters at the end. I already put so much into this answer, so I kept it short. The reader can turn to the manual for more epic reading. The link is there ..

Comment: Fair enough on the length. It just felt odd after all that talk about how to name output columns to not actually use output column names at all, but a completely different solution to the problem. Perhaps just before the example say "Rewritten ... using another alternative, which is referring to output columns by their position" or something. (Also, those aren't positional *parameters* surely? Just positional *references*...)

Comment: @IMSoP: You are right, the term is misleading. Updated accordingly.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks so much for the detailed response.  Works very well for my use case.

Answer (score 18):

can you please try this:
replace the case statement with the below one

```
Sum(CASE WHEN attempt.result = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Count,
```

Comment: I had no idea that you could wrap a case in sum and avoid the group by nightmare that follows complex case statements. The possibilities...

Answer (score 6):

Aliases can be used only if they were introduced in the preceding step. So aliases in the `SELECT` clause can be used in the `ORDER BY` but not the `GROUP BY` clause.

Reference: Microsoft T-SQL Documentation for further reading.

```
FROM
ON
JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the other two non COUNT columns to the GROUP BY:

```
select CURRENT_DATE-1 AS day, 
model.name, 
attempt.type, 
CASE WHEN attempt.result = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
count(*) 
from attempt attempt, prod_hw_id prod_hw_id, model model
where time >= '2013-11-06 00:00:00'  
AND time < '2013-11-07 00:00:00'
AND attempt.hard_id = prod_hw_id.hard_id
AND prod_hw_id.model_id = model.model_id
group by 1,2,3,4
order by model.name, attempt.type, attempt.result;
```

Comment: I assume you mean to add "day" to the group by?  I tried that and the result is the same.  Did you mean something else?  I have 5 fields in the select and 3 are already there, so day is the only other non-count field.

Comment: Yes. i put them on my answer: 1,2,3,4. All except the COUNT.

Answer (score 2):

For TSQL I like to encapsulate case statements in an outer apply. This prevents me from having to have the case statement written twice, allows reference to the case statement by alias in future joins and avoids the need for positional references.

```
select oa.day, 
model.name, 
attempt.type, 
oa.result
COUNT(*) MyCount 
FROM attempt attempt, prod_hw_id prod_hw_id, model model
WHERE time >= '2013-11-06 00:00:00'  
AND time < '2013-11-07 00:00:00'
AND attempt.hard_id = prod_hw_id.hard_id
AND prod_hw_id.model_id = model.model_id
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE-1 AS day,
     CASE WHEN attempt.result = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END result
    ) oa    
group by oa.day, 
model.name, 
attempt.type, 
oa.result
order by model.name, attempt.type, oa.result;
```

Comment: How is TSQL be applicable to a [postgresql] question? (It isn't.)

Comment: Oddly enough ^^ when i googled how to avoid duplicate case statement in group by this answer helped me out (yes for tSQL :D )