# How to make GROUP BY as a parameter without using CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have the following table with the following tables and values and types.

```
create table example  (
fname text,
lname text,
value int);

insert into example values
('doge','coin',123),
('bit','coin',434),
('lite','coin',565),
('doge','meme',183),
('bit','meme',453),
('lite','meme',433);

create type resultrow as (
nam text,
amount int);
```

I would like to write a function, that groups by a parameter I give to the function.
This example works:

```
do $$
declare
 my_parameter text;
 results resultrow[];
begin

my_parameter = 'last';

results := array(select row( case when my_parameter = 'first' then fname
            when my_parameter = 'last' then lname
       end,
       sum(salary))::resultrow
  from example
  group by case when my_parameter = 'first' then fname
            when my_parameter = 'last' then lname
       end);

raise notice '%', results;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I have been told, that CASE WHEN decisions are really expensive. One obvious solution would be to create the select statements twice:

```
if my_parameter = 'first' then
  results := array(select row(fname,sum(salary))::resultrow
  from example
  group by fname);
end if;

if my_parameter = 'last' then
  results := array(select row(lname,sum(salary))::resultrow
  from example
  group by lname);
end if;
```

But this leads to a lot of ugly duplicated code.

Is there another solution to make the group by parameterisable?

Comment: "*I have been told..*" - you should test that before jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `case`, you can use this:

```
with cte(name, salary) as (
    select fname, salary from example where my_parameter = 'first'
    union all
    select lname, salary from example where my_parameter = 'last'
) 
select name, sum(salary)
from cte
group by name
```

But, actually, it's better to test, I've not heard that `case` is expensive.

If you'll find that `case` is not expensive, I still suggest use subquery or cte to avoid code duplication, like:

```
with cte(name, salary) as (
    select
        case
            when my_parameter = 'first' then fname
            when my_parameter = 'last' then lname
        end as name,
        salary
    from example
) 
select name, sum(salary)
from cte
group by name
```

Comment: This worked really well, and looks good in the code, thanks I really like the second case solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplify what you have:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _param  text := 'last'; -- one can assign at declaration time
   results resultrow[];
BEGIN

results := ARRAY(
   SELECT t::resultrow     -- refer to table alias to get whole row
   FROM (
      SELECT CASE _param   -- simple "switched" CASE
               WHEN 'first' THEN fname
               WHEN 'last'  THEN lname
             END
            ,sum(salary)
      FROM   example
      GROUP  BY 1          -- simpler with positional reference
      ) t
   );

RAISE NOTICE '%', results;

END
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Using [**simple `CASE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) syntax variant. This way the expression is only evaluated once and the syntax is simpler. Since your question refers to `CASE` - even if that's hardly relevant.

Also using a **positional reference** in the `GROUP BY` clause. This seems relevant to the title of your question. More explanation in these related answers:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
[GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)

This kind of query ***can*** be very inefficient. It's not a problem of the (very cheap!) `CASE` statement per se. It's because the planner has to provide for varying input in the first column and may be forced to use a generic, less optimized plan.

#### Dynamic SQL

I assume the actual goal is to write a function that takes `my_parameter`. Use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`, which will likely result in a superior query plan, i.e. superior performance. There are lots of code example here, [try a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D%20return%20query%20execute).

Also, I return a set of `resultrow` instead of the awkward `ARRAY` you had in your example (since you cannot return from a `DO` statement):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_salaray_for_param(_param text)
  RETURNS SETOF resultrow AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _fld    text :=
      CASE _param
        WHEN 'first' THEN 'fname'  -- SQL injection not possible
        WHEN 'last'  THEN 'lname'
      END;
BEGIN

IF _fld IS NULL THEN               -- exception for invalid params
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected value for _param: %', _param;
END IF;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
   SELECT ' || _fld || ', sum(salary)
   FROM   example
   GROUP  BY 1';                   -- query is very simple now

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_salaray_for_param('first');
```

BTW, the [plpgsql assignment operator is `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace) (not `=`).

Comment: As has been mentioned more than once, run some test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to compare the actual performance of the various solutions. You might drop a line or two in a comment to tell us about the results.