# SELECT encrypted items from a table using LIKE on an expression

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, encryption

I am using the [Chinook Database](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/55681) as a way to test a concept using encryption. I found that I could use the `LIKE` key word if I did:

```
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt("Name", '22') FROM "Artist" WHERE pgp_sym_decrypt("Name", '22') LIKE '%a%';
```

I'm currently trying to avoid having to use the second `pgp_sym_decrypt("Name", '22')` if at all possible thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to use a column alias. but that's not possible in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause, which only reference input columns, not output columns - as defined by the SQL standard. Details in this related answer:
[GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)

You would have to use a subquery as wrapper, which kind of defies your aim to shorten the code and may be slower if the optimizer fails to see through your stunt:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt("Name", '22') AS expr FROM "Artist") sub
WHERE  expr LIKE '%a%';
```

Comment: @JJspacer: I suggest you open a new question with all the necessary details for [\[postgresql-performance\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). Be sure to search for related questions and answers first - there are quite a few here. Generally, searching through encrypted strings - especially passwords - is tricky.