# Count with condition using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mySQL.

I want to show the table with count for the following table as shown below:

Table: test

```
create table test
(
age int,
sex text
);
```

Insertion of some records:

```
insert into test values(10,'Male');
insert into test values(15,'Male');
insert into test values(20,'Male');
insert into test values(25,'Male');
insert into test values(30,'Male');
insert into test values(10,'Female');
insert into test values(15,'Female');
insert into test values(40,'Male');
insert into test values(50,'Female');
insert into test values(60,'Female');
```

**Note**: Now I want to show the count of male and female between the age range in the table.

**Expected Result**:

```
 Age-Range   sex    count
 ------------------------
  10-20      Male    3
  10-20      Female  2
  25-40      Male    3
  45-60      Female  2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although counting the males and females from a set is pretty easy in mysql. You can use conditional `sum` ex.

```
select 
age,
sum(sex='Male') as male_count
sum(sex='Female') as female_count
from test
group by age ;
```

But in your case you need to consider the range as well, so its not straight forward. Here is a way you can achieve what you are looking at, but there may be other better way to do it.

```
select 
p.`range`,
p.sex,
sum(p.`count`) as `count`
from
(
 select 
  x.`range`,
  y.`sex`,
  y.`age`,
  y.`count` from( 
    select '10-20' as `range`,20 as `upper` ,10 as `lower`
    union all 
    select '25-40' as `range`,40 as `upper` ,25 as `lower`
    union all 
    select '45-60' as `range`,60 as `upper` ,45 as `lower`
  )x
  left join(
    select
    sex,
    count(*) as `count`,
    age from test
    group by age,sex

  )y
  on y.age >= x.`lower` and y.age <= x.`upper`
)p

group by p.`range`,p.sex
;
```