# SQL Group By with Case

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case

I need to create a simplified report where I list all of the sources of my sales and break it down only for miscellaneous stuff.

The reason why I said **simplified** is because I am trying to group some stuff together which means that all animal sales are supposed to be labeled **Boarding Charges**.

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN aoi.is_animal = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(aot.name)
        ELSE 'Boarding Charges'
    END AS display_name,
    aoi.is_animal,
    CASE
        WHEN aot.name = 'Misc.' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS show_details,
    SUM(aoi.quantity * aoi.unit_price) as total
FROM ANIMAL_ORDER ao
LEFT JOIN ANIMAL_ORDER_ITEM aoi ON aoi.order_id = ao.id
LEFT JOIN ANIMAL_ORDER_TYPE aot ON aot.id = aoi.order_type_id
WHERE ao.order_stage != 'CANCELLED'
GROUP BY
    aot.name,
    CASE
        WHEN aoi.is_animal = 'N' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END, aoi.is_animal
```

I'm trying to make this simple for now so I'm not worried about the `Misc.` stuff - I just added a column for it to say `Y` or `N` temporarily.

The query above results to something like this:

```
# Resulting table

DISPLAY_NAME            IS_ANIMAL   SHOW_DETAILS       TOTALS
-------------------------------------------------------------
Boarding Charges        Y           N                 8039.53
Truck Delivery Fee      N           N                 1005.21
Misc.                   N           Y                  237.16
Cancellation Fee        N           N                   45.00
Late Fee                N           N                  410.25
Courier Fee             N           N                 1338.40
Boarding Charges        Y           N                  311.27
Boarding Charges        Y           N                 7341.19
```

As you can see the **Boarding Charges** aren't grouped together and I understand what the reason is - I have `aot.name` in the `GROUP BY` clause. The only reason why it's there is because when I try to remove it, I get an error on `TO_CHAR(aot.name)` saying that it's not a `GROUP BY` expression.

I just want to have all the **Boarding Charges** grouped together and sum up their totals.

#### Additional Information

I'm trying to use the approaches mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a  group by display_name   you should repeat the same condition in group by

```
  SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN aoi.is_animal = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(aot.name)
        ELSE 'Boarding Charges'
    END AS display_name,
    aoi.is_animal,
    CASE
        WHEN aot.name = 'Misc.' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS show_details,
    SUM(aoi.quantity * aoi.unit_price) as total
FROM ANIMAL_ORDER ao
LEFT JOIN ANIMAL_ORDER_ITEM aoi ON aoi.order_id = ao.id
LEFT JOIN ANIMAL_ORDER_TYPE aot ON aot.id = aoi.order_type_id
WHERE ao.order_stage != 'CANCELLED'
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN aoi.is_animal = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(aot.name)
        ELSE 'Boarding Charges'
    END ,
    aoi.is_animal,
    CASE
        WHEN aot.name = 'Misc.' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END
```

Comment: Seems to work as long as I remove the aliases on the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: In oracle the query should work also using the columns alias .. i  have used  the flat code  just for sample  ..because aot.name is not equivalent  to the case for display_name ..anyway i have update the asnwer also for alias  ... let me know

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I get an error saying `ORA-00904: "show_details": invalid identifier`.

Comment: @scaisEdge - what the OP is saying is that the "AS show_details" at the end does not work - and obviously it doesn't (I assume in ANY flavor of SQL). Of course the other aliases do work, throughout the CASE expression; but you can't alias the result of the CASE expression in GROUP BY.

Comment: @mathguy  . answer updated remobìving the alias group by

Comment: @scaisEdge You need to remove the `AS display_name` and `AS show_details` on the group by clause.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio   . yes correct .. copy and paste with half brain .. off .. .. i have udpdate the answer

Comment: @scaisEdge as long as you can still turn it on you're okay. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @PatrickGregorio   many .. thanks  my brain  model ..is an old model ...  not full multitasking ..

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN aoi.is_animal = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(aot.name)
             ELSE 'Boarding Charges'
        END) AS display_name,
       (CASE WHEN aoi.is_animal = 'N' THEN aoi.is_animal END) as is_animal,
       (CASE WHEN aoi.is_animal <> 'N' THEN NULL
             WHEN aot.name = 'Misc.' THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
        END) AS show_details,
       SUM(aoi.quantity * aoi.unit_price) as total
FROM . . .
```

The idea is to set the other two keys to `NULL` for that "Boarding Charges" rows.  The `GROUP BY` should change to match the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: This did fix the problem of not being able to group all the **Boarding Charges** but I don't understand what the purpose of having a `null` on the other 2 columns. I think I prefer the answer of @scaisEdge. - Still upvoted.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio . . . Well, it would seem possible for the other columns to have different values for "Boarding Charges" rows.  That would then spread the results onto multiple rows.  This version *guarantees* that "Boarding Charges" are only on one row, regardless of the values of the other columns.  Hence, it is a more resilient answer to the question.