# Trying to reduce the number of rows in query results to 1 per works order number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compile the results of a table I'm working on to only return 1 row per works order number. I'm sure there's something simple that I'm missing, but I just can't quite get it there.

Here's what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @PreviousStart SmallDateTime
DECLARE @PreviousEnd SmallDateTime
SET @PreviousStart = '11-01-2023 00:00:00'
SET @PreviousEnd = '11-30-2023 00:00:00'

Select WorksOrderNumber [Works Order Number],
Case When ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 3 THEN AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency END as [Truss Lumber],
Case When ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 4 THEN AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency END as [Truss Plates],
Case When ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 5 THEN AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency END as [Truss Labor],
Case When ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 6 THEN AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency END as [Truss Overhead]
from WorksOrderheader WOH
LEFT OUTER JOIN WorksOrderLine WOL on WOH.WorksOrderID = WOL.WorksOrderID AND WOL.ProductKitManufacturedProcessID is not null
Where BranchID = 1 AND
WorksOrderNumber != 0 AND
DateTimeCreated between @PreviousStart and @PreviousEnd AND
Description like '%Floor%'
Group by WorksOrderNumber, ProductKitManufacturedProcessID, AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency
Order By WorksOrderNumber
```

And here are the results I'm getting:

| Works Order Number | Truss Lumber | Truss Plates | Truss Labor | Truss Overhead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101782 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1300 |
| 101782 | 3600 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 101782 | NULL | 2100 | NULL | NULL |
| 101782 | NULL | NULL | 3500 | NULL |

All I'm looking for is to get all 4 of these rows to be reflected in one row. The data it gives me is the data I'm looking for. The @PreviousStart and @PreviousEnd are just being used as filters for the smartview I'm using this code for in Bistrack, and those are fine. Just stuck on getting everything down to one row per works order.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement), use an aggregate function, like `SUM` of `COUNT`, on the columns where you now have a `CASE WHEN....END` construction.

Comment: Normally you would just put a `MAX()` around each case expression (assuming other values are always NULL). Do you really need to group by more than one column?

Comment: I see that each result has a value and 3 NULLs --  Would there ever be a time where - say - `Truss Lumber` has 2 values that need to be added together?  OR is it always going to be 1 value per case?

Comment: This could be done as a PIVOT

Comment: If you want one row per _anything_, start with `group by [that_anything]` and add no more fields to the `group by`. Adding extra fields to your group by is a common sign one has misunderstood what `group by` is meant for. I think @Isolated comment is probably what you're after.

Comment: @Isolated, I only want to group by the works order number, that's correct. Apologies if it's a pretty basic thing (less than a year of using sql under my belt)  but where would I put that MAX()? This does seem to be exactly what I'm after, but I just want to clarify where exactly I would put that. When I put it around the AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency column, I get the same results. Apologies if this is a super basic question haha

Comment: @Purpleman101 Like this... `select col1, max(case when .... end) as truss_lumber, max(case when... end) as truss_plates.... from table group by col1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically describing a `pivot` of sorts. You have a bunch of values in essentially name/value format, and you want to get columns out of them. You said you wanted a single row per `WorksOrderNumber` so that's your first clue you need a `group by WorksOrderNumber`.

Now you need to project each of those 4 rows into their own columns. The way I like to do that is using a conditional `max` expression. Basically, I'm using `max` somewhat arbitrarily because I need *some* function to aggregate down to a single row. So I start with basically what you've already done, but throw a `max` around the `case` expression. That will eliminate all the null values, and leave you with the value you actually want.

Here's a pared down refactor of your code (I used `iif`, but that's essentially equivalent to `case`)

```
select
    [Works Order Number] = WorksOrderNumber,
    [Truss Lumber] = max(iif(ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 3, AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency, null)),
    [Truss Plates] = max(iif(ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 4, AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency, null)),
    [Truss Labor] = max(iif(ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 5, AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency, null)),
    [Truss Overhead] = max(iif(ProductKitManufacturedProcessID = 6, AVOOptionTotalCostInCurrency, null))
from WorksOrderheader WOH
left outer join WorksOrderLine WOL
    on WOH.WorksOrderID = WOL.WorksOrderID
        and WOL.ProductKitManufacturedProcessID is not null
group by WorksOrderNumber
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much, I've never done a query like this before, but that got me exactly the results I was looking for.

Thank you and everyone who commented so quickly!

Comment: Glad to hear it!