# Find most common elements in array with a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.3, lateral

I have a table of rows with the following structure `name TEXT, favorite_colors TEXT[], group_name INTEGER` where each row has a list of everyone's favorite colors and the group that person belongs to. How can I `GROUP BY group_name` and return a list of the most common colors in each group?

Could you do a combination of `int[] && int[]` to set for overlap, `int[] & int[]` to get the intersection and then something else to count and rank?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT group_name, color, count(*) AS ct
FROM (
   SELECT group_name, unnest(favorite_colors) AS color
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,3 DESC;
```

#### Better with a [`LATERAL JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html)

In Postgres **9.3 or later** this is the cleaner form:

```
SELECT group_name, color, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl t, unnest(t.favorite_colors) AS color
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,3 DESC;
```

The above is shorthand for

```
...
FROM tbl t
JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.favorite_colors) AS color ON TRUE
...
```

And like with any other `INNER JOIN`, it would exclude rows without color (`favorite_colors IS NULL`) - as did the first query.

To *include* such rows in the result, use instead:

```
SELECT group_name, color, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.favorite_colors) AS color ON TRUE
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,3 DESC;
```

You can easily aggregate the "most common" colors per group in the next step, but you'd need to define "most common colors" first ...

#### Most common colors

As per comment, pick colors with > 3 occurrences.

```
SELECT t.group_name, color, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl t, unnest(t.favorite_colors) AS color
GROUP  BY 1,2
HAVING count(*) > 3
ORDER  BY 1,3 DESC;
```

To aggregate the top colors in an array (in descending order):

```
SELECT group_name, array_agg(color) AS top_colors
FROM  (
   SELECT group_name, color
   FROM   tbl t, unnest(t.favorite_colors) AS color
   GROUP  BY 1,2
   HAVING count(*) > 3
   ORDER  BY 1, count(*) DESC
   ) sub
GROUP BY 1;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94475/7) demonstrating all.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain how grouping by those integers achieves this? If I want to put in a `HAVING` so I could ask for only the colors that have more than 3 occurrences in a group, where would I put the `HAVING`. I keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: @mhkeller: Consider the addendum and the updated fiddle.