# Use table alias in another query to traverse a tree

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select * from (
   select p1.c as child, p1.p as parent, 1 as height
   from parent as p1
   where (p1.c=3 or p1.c=8);

   union

   select p2.c as child, p2.c as parent, 2 as height
   from parent as p2 
   where (p1.child=3 or p1.child=8) and p1.parent = p2.child;
)
```

The schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE parent(p int, c int);
```

I'm trying to find a path from the *child* to the *root*. [Edit] And append the number of edges we have to traverse.
The goal is to join the child's parent with its parent, something like:

```
(8, 2, 1)
(8, 5, 2) -> 8 is the lowest child, 2 is its parent, and 5 it's 2 parent.
```

Some sample data:

```
10 | 5
10 | 12
12 | 3
12 | 4
4  | 6
4  | 7
5  | 11
5  | 2
2  | 8
```

How can I use the reference for the first query `p1` inside the second query that will form `p2`? 
After that I should have;

```
(8,2,1)
(3,12,1)
(3,10,2)
(8,5,2)
```

Thus I already will know what to do to complete what I want.

Comment: If using Oracle, look up CONNECT BY, and maybe mix in a LISTAGG.

Comment: The examples look fine to me. The third column is the "height", the distance between the nodes. The first column is the "child", the second column is the "parent" (height 1), or "grandparent" (height 2).

Comment: @spencer7593: Now, *that* adds up. Thanks.

Comment: Is your tree limited to three levels like in the example or are you looking for a general solution for n levels?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with 4 different DBMS?

Answer (score 4):

#### Question asked

You *cannot* reference a *table alias* from one subquery in another query on the same level (or in another leg of a `UNION` query). A table alias is only visible in the query itself and subqueries of it.
You *could* reference output columns of a subquery on the same query level with a [`LATERAL JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-select.html). Example:
[Find most common elements in array with a group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033312/find-most-common-elements-in-array-with-a-group-by/21033693#21033693)

#### Solution for small maximum number of levels

For only a handful of levels (if you *know* the maximum), you can use a simple query:

- `LEFT JOIN` to n-1 instances of the table itself
- Use `COALESCE` and a `CASE` statement to pin down the root and hight,

```
SELECT p1.c AS child, COALESCE(p3.p, p2.p, p1.p) AS parent
      ,CASE
          WHEN p3.p IS NOT NULL THEN 3
          WHEN p2.p IS NOT NULL THEN 2
          ELSE 1
       END AS height
FROM   parent p1
LEFT   JOIN parent p2 ON p2.c = p1.p
LEFT   JOIN parent p3 ON p3.c = p2.p
WHERE  p1.c IN (3, 8)
ORDER  BY p1.c;
```

This is standard SQL and should work **in all 4 RDBMS** you tagged.

#### Generic solution for arbitrary number of levels

Use a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) like @Ken already advised.

- In the recursive leg *keep the child* for every row, only advance the parent.
- In the outer `SELECT`, only keep a the row with the greatest `height` per child.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT c AS child, p AS parent, 1 AS height
   FROM   parent
   WHERE  c IN (3, 8)

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c.child, p.p AS parent, c.height + 1
   FROM   cte    c
   JOIN   parent p ON p.c = c.parent
   -- WHERE  c.height < 10  -- to safeguard against endless loops if necessary
   )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (child) *
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY child, height DESC;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is specific to **Postgres**. Explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

The rest would work in a similar fashion in **Oracle** and even **SQLite**, but not in MySQL which doesn't support CTEs.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/593f1/2) demonstrating both.

Answer (score 2):

In *Postgres*, I would recommend looking at a `WITH RECURSIVE` *CTE*:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html

It's perfect for modeling tree-like structures such as parent-child relationships, be it an entire tree, a subtree, etc.

There are many examples in the *Postgres* doc, including for dealing with tree-like structures specifically, which should apply to your case (albeit with some adaptation of your query to fit the `WITH RECURSIVE` mold).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to reference a table alias from the first SELECT in the second SELECT (following a UNION or UNION ALL set operator. You can in a correlated subquery, but that has to be within the context of the same SELECT.)

Also, you need to ditch the semicolons within the statement; MySQL is going to see that as the end of the statement.

For **MySQL**, you're definitely got a workable approach to solving this problem, using separate queries for each "height", and combining the results with a `UNION` set operator. Likely, you want to use a `UNION ALL` set operator for performance. (If you don't need the extra step of identifying and removing duplicates. Also, it's not necessary to use an inline view.

```
SELECT p1.c  AS child
     , p1.p  AS parent
     , 1     AS height
  FROM parent p1
 WHERE p1.c IN (3,8)
 UNION ALL
SELECT p1.c  AS child
     , p2.p  AS parent
     , 2     AS height
  FROM parent p1
  JOIN parent p2
    ON p2.c = p1.p
 WHERE p1.c IN (3,8)
```

Just to demonstrate how this can be extended to a height of 3, adding another JOIN to the same table,  with alias of `p3`.

```
 UNION ALL
SELECT p1.c  AS child
     , p3.p  AS parent
     , 3     AS height
  FROM parent p1
  JOIN parent p2 ON p2.c = p1.p
  JOIN parent p3 ON p3.c = p2.p
 WHERE p1.c IN (3,8)
```

---

**NOTE**

Originally, I only noticed this was tagged for MySQL.

With Oracle, you could make use of the recursive `CONNECT BY` form of SELECT, to get an equivalent result without a `UNION`.