# How to merge JSONB field in a tree structure?

Tags: postgresql, tree, recursive-query, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

I have a table in Postgres which stores a tree structure. Each node has a `jsonb` field: `params_diff`:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (id INT, parent_id INT, params_diff JSONB);
INSERT INTO tree VALUES
  (1, NULL, '{ "some_key": "some value" }'::jsonb)
, (2, 1,    '{ "some_key": "other value", "other_key": "smth" }'::jsonb)
, (3, 2,    '{ "other_key": "smth else" }'::jsonb);
```

The thing I need is to select a node by `id` with additional generated `params` field which contains the result of merging all `params_diff` from the whole parents chain:

```
SELECT tree.*, /* some magic here */ AS params FROM tree WHERE id = 3;

 id | parent_id |        params_diff         |                        params
----+-----------+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
  3 |         2 | {"other_key": "smth else"} | {"some_key": "other value", "other_key": "smth else"}
```

Comment: It's unclear how to "merge parents chain" exactly. Only take the "last"  (furthest away from the root) value for each key to form a list? Sort order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) can do the job. Example:

- [Use table alias in another query to traverse a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622940/use-table-alias-in-another-query-to-traverse-a-tree/24623849#24623849)

We just need a more magic to decompose, process and re-assemble the JSON result. I am assuming from your example, that you want each key once only, with the first value in the search path (bottom-up):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, parent_id, params_diff, 1 AS lvl
   FROM   tree
   WHERE  id = 3

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.params_diff, c.lvl + 1
   FROM   cte  c
   JOIN   tree t ON t.id = c.parent_id
   )
SELECT id, parent_id, params_diff
    , (SELECT json_object(array_agg(key   ORDER BY lvl)
                        , array_agg(value ORDER BY lvl))::jsonb
        FROM  (
           SELECT key, value
           FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT ON (key)
                       p.key, p.value, c.lvl
                FROM   cte c, jsonb_each_text(c.params_diff) p
                ORDER  BY p.key, c.lvl
                ) sub1
           ORDER  BY lvl
           ) sub2
       ) AS params

FROM   cte
WHERE  id = 3;
```

#### How?

1. Walk the tree with a classic recursive CTE.
2. Create a derived table with all keys and values with [`jsonb_each_text()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a `LATERAL JOIN`, remember the level in the search path (`lvl`).
3. Use `DISTINCT ON` to get the "first" (lowest `lvl`) `value` for each `key`. Details:

   - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
4. Sort and aggregate resulting keys and values and feed the arrays to [`json_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) to build the final `params` value.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bc4a4/14) (only as far as pg 9.3 can go with `json` instead of `jsonb`).

Comment: This function works but it casts all the values to strings (including nested objects and arrays).
Is there a way to make it keep the value type and also merge nested objects?

Comment: Ok, I managed that myself. Basically I changed `json_object` call to `json_object_agg(key, value)` and `jsonb_each_text` to `jsonb_each(c.params_diff)`.