# Create table from multiple calls to a function returning record

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, set-returning-functions, lateral

I have a function that does some basic statistics on a range of data based on a start and stop timestamp:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cal(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, OUT Date_Time timestamp with time zone, OUT avg numeric, OUT stddev numeric, OUT Rstedv_per numeric) 
AS $$
SELECT
    max(datetime) as Date_Time,
    avg(SO2) AS Mean,
    stddev_samp(so2) as STD_DEV,
    stddev_samp(so2)/avg(SO2)*100 as Rstedv_Per
FROM Table43
WHERE datetime > $1 AND datetime < $2;
$$
 LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This works great with a simple single select such as this:

```
select * FROM
 cal('2014-08-02 05:29:00', '2014-08-02 05:32:00')
```

But now I am having trouble creating another function, or even a select statement that can combine multiple calls of the 'cal' function. For example I want to return a table that contains three time periods. So the return would be 4 columns by 3 rows:

```
'2014-08-02 05:29:00', '2014-08-02 05:32:00'
'2014-08-02 05:35:00', '2014-08-02 05:39:00'
'2014-08-02 05:45:00', '2014-08-02 05:49:00'
```

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT * FROM cal(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [**`VALUES`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-values.html) expression to provide multiple rows of input dates.
Then ...

#### For all versions of Postgres

```
SELECT cal(a, b)
FROM  (
   VALUES 
      ('2014-08-02 05:29'::timestamp, '2014-08-02 05:32'::timestamp)
    , ('2014-08-02 05:35', '2014-08-02 05:39')
    , ('2014-08-02 05:45', '2014-08-02 05:39')
   ) v(a, b);
```

You can replace the `VALUES` expression with an actual table.

This returns whole rows as a single column (instead of individual columns). You could decompose in place with `(cal(a, b)).*`. While this works, it is inefficient. Due to a weakness in the Postgres parser, this would result in multiple evaluation of the function. Detailed explanation:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query/18370271#18370271)

Instead, use a subquery for better performance:

```
SELECT (rec).*
FROM  (
    SELECT cal(a, b)
    FROM  (
       VALUES 
          ('2014-08-02 05:29'::timestamp, '2014-08-02 05:32'::timestamp)
        , ('2014-08-02 05:35', '2014-08-02 05:39')
        , ('2014-08-02 05:45', '2014-08-02 05:39')
       ) v(a, b)
   ) sub;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/c19b1/3) (for pg 8.3 to demonstrate it works in old versions).

Since set-returning functions in the SELECT list are frowned upon by some, and are non-standard SQL.

#### Postgres 9.3+

That's the main reason why Postgres 9.3 introduced (SQL-standard compliant) [**`LATERAL JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
SELECT f.*
FROM  (
   VALUES 
      ('2014-08-02 05:29'::timestamp, '2014-08-02 05:32'::timestamp)
    , ('2014-08-02 05:35', '2014-08-02 05:39')
    , ('2014-08-02 05:45', '2014-08-02 05:39')
   ) v(a,b)
  , cal(v.a, v.b) f;
```

The `LATERAL JOIN` is *implicit* here, since the second item in the FROM list references the previous table explicitly. Details:

- [Find most common elements in array with a group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033312/find-most-common-elements-in-array-with-a-group-by/21033693#21033693)

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c19b1/1) for current Postgres 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are parameters you would need something like:

```
select * 
FROM cal('2014-08-02 05:29:00', '2014-08-02 05:32:00')
union all
select * 
FROM cal('2014-08-02 05:35:00', '2014-08-02 05:39:00')
union all
select * 
FROM cal('2014-08-02 05:45:00', '2014-08-02 05:39:00')
```

**PostgreSQL 9.0+**

```
select cal(a, b)
from 
    values( 
    ('2014-08-02 05:29:00', '2014-08-02 05:32:00'),
    ('2014-08-02 05:29:00', '2014-08-02 05:32:00'),
    ('2014-08-02 05:29:00', '2014-08-02 05:32:00')
    ) as dates (a, b)
```

If your dates come from a table and your are working with **Postresql 9.3**:

```
select cal.*
FROM 
  (select '2014-08-02 05:29:00' a, '2014-08-02 05:32:00' b
      from foo_table) as dates
left join lateral cal(dates.a, dates.b) cal on true
```