# Selecting sum and running balance for last 18 months with generate_series

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, generate-series, running-balance

I have this working query, but I need to add all months to my result, no matter if the items sold during that month:

```
select * from (
select
to_char(max(change_date), 'YYYY-MON')::varchar(8) as yyyymmm,
max(change_date) as yearmonth,
sum(vic.sold_qty / item_size.qty)::numeric(18,2) as sold_qty,  -- sold monthly
sum(sum(on_hand)) OVER (PARTITION BY vic.item_id order by year,month) as on_hand --running balance
from (((view_item_change vic
left join item on vic.item_id = item.item_id)
left join item_size on item_size.item_id = vic.item_id and item_size.name = item.sell_size)
left join item_plu on vic.item_id = item_plu.item_id and item_plu.seq_num = 0)
where 1 = 1   -- cannot limit date here as its used to show running balance.
and vic.change_date < current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer --show only till end of last month
and item.item_id = (select item_id from item_plu where number = '51515')
group by vic.item_id, year, month
) as t 
where yearmonth > current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer - 540 -- 18 months
```

which gives me something like this:

```
"2013-JUN";"2013-06-29";0.00;7.0000
"2013-JUL";"2013-07-22";0.00;6.0000
"2013-AUG";"2013-08-28";2.00;4.0000
"2013-SEP";"2013-09-02";0.00;4.0000
"2013-OCT";"2013-10-28";0.00;4.0000
"2013-NOV";"2013-11-15";0.00;4.0000
"2013-DEC";"2013-12-16";0.00;6.0000
"2014-FEB";"2014-02-10";1.00;5.0000
"2014-APR";"2014-04-09";0.00;5.0000
```

But I also want to show the months `2014-JAN` and `2014-MAR` so that my chart will be better time scaled.

I know how to do the `generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 month')` intervals, but I can't quite see how I can join this series to the result set above.

I accepted first answer, but after 2 weeks of testing, found a problem. The left join to the series and then adding a coalesce to show 0's and not nulls for the empty months causes a problem wit the running balance.

Resulting query:

```
SELECT yyyymmm, yyyymmm, 
coalesce(sold_qty,0) sold_qty, coalesce(on_hand,0) on_hand
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', month_series)::date as yyyymmm
   FROM   generate_series(current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer - 540  
   ,current_date- date_part('day',current_date)::integer
   , interval '1 month') month_series
   ) month_series
LEFT  JOIN (
    select * from (
        select
        date_trunc('month', max(change_date))::date as yyyymmm,
        max(change_date) as yearmonth,
        sum(vic.sold_qty / item_size.qty)::numeric(18,2) as sold_qty,
        sum(sum(on_hand)) OVER (PARTITION BY vic.item_id order by year,month) as on_hand
        from (((view_item_change vic
        left join item on vic.item_id = item.item_id)
        left join item_size on item_size.item_id = vic.item_id and item_size.name = item.sell_size)
        left join item_plu on vic.item_id = item_plu.item_id and item_plu.seq_num = 0)
        where 1 = 1   -- cannot limit date here as its used to show running balance.
        --vic.change_date >= current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer - 730  -- only get results for last 
        --show only till end of last month
        and vic.change_date <= current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer
        and item.item_id = (select item_id from item_plu where number = '19M7077')
        group by vic.item_id, year, month
    ) as a 
    where yyyymmm > current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer - 540 -- 18 months
) q USING (yyyymmm)
order by 1
```

Results I get:

```
"2013-07-01";"2013-07-01";0;0
"2013-08-01";"2013-08-01";0;0
"2013-09-01";"2013-09-01";1.00;53.0000
"2013-10-01";"2013-10-01";0;0
"2013-11-01";"2013-11-01";0;0
"2013-12-01";"2013-12-01";0.00;53.0000
"2014-01-01";"2014-01-01";0.00;52.0000
"2014-02-01";"2014-02-01";0;0
"2014-03-01";"2014-03-01";0;0
"2014-04-01";"2014-04-01";0;0
```

But I want:

```
"2013-07-01";"2013-07-01";0;53.0000
"2013-08-01";"2013-08-01";0;53.0000
"2013-09-01";"2013-09-01";1.00;53.0000
"2013-10-01";"2013-10-01";0;53.0000
"2013-11-01";"2013-11-01";0;0;53.0000
"2013-12-01";"2013-12-01";0.00;53.0000
"2014-01-01";"2014-01-01";0.00;52.0000
"2014-02-01";"2014-02-01";0;0;52.0000
"2014-03-01";"2014-03-01";0;0;52.0000
"2014-04-01";"2014-04-01";0;0;52.0000
```

#### Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
  item_id character(22) NOT NULL,
  version integer NOT NULL,
  created_by character varying(16) NOT NULL,
  updated_by character varying(16),
  inactive_by character varying(16),
  created_on date NOT NULL,
  updated_on date,
  inactive_on date,
  external_id numeric(14,0),
  description character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  dept_id character(22),
  subdept_id character(22),
  sell_size character varying(8) NOT NULL,
  purch_size character varying(8) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE item_change
(
  item_id character(22) NOT NULL,
  size_name character varying(8) NOT NULL,
  store_id character(22) NOT NULL,
  change_date date NOT NULL,
  on_hand numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,   -- sum column / item_id = total on_hand
  total_cost numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  on_order numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  sold_qty numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  sold_cost numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  sold_price numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  recv_qty numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  recv_cost numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  adj_qty numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  adj_cost numeric(18,4) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE item_size
(
  item_id character(22) NOT NULL,
  seq_num integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(8) NOT NULL,
  qty numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  weight numeric(18,4) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT item_size_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id, seq_num),
  CONSTRAINT item_size_c0 FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
      REFERENCES item (item_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT item_size_c1 UNIQUE (item_id, name)
);

CREATE TABLE item_plu
(
  item_id character(22) NOT NULL,
  seq_num integer NOT NULL,
  "number" character varying(18) NOT NULL,
  size_name character varying(8)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_item_change AS 
 SELECT date_part('year'::text, item_change.change_date) AS year,
date_part('month'::text, item_change.change_date) AS month,
date_part('week'::text, item_change.change_date) AS week,
date_part('quarter'::text, item_change.change_date) AS quarter,
date_part('dow'::text, item_change.change_date) AS dow,
item_change.item_id,
item_change.size_name,
item_change.store_id,
item_change.change_date,
item_change.on_hand,
item_change.total_cost,
item_change.on_order,
item_change.sold_qty,
item_change.sold_cost,
item_change.sold_price,
item_change.recv_qty,
item_change.recv_cost,
item_change.adj_qty,
item_change.adj_cost
FROM item_change;
```

There is only a single row per month because I also do a group by year, month.  As you see, the view has the year, quarter, month, week, dow columns for easier reporting.

To get working data for this, if required, I can do it, but it would require manually creating it. I have simplified the tables and left out all constraints and some columns.

Comment: You `GROUP BY item_id`, but then there is not `item_id` in the result and only a single row per month? This is odd. Also, `year`and `date` and `change_date` are not table-qualified, making this a guessing game. Would be much simpler to solve with actual table definitions and sample data. At least table-qualify all columns in the query to give us a fighting chance.

Comment: I don't see the definition for `item_size`? Your version of Postgres?

Comment: added item_size above.  Postgres v 9.3.

Comment: Either we get *multiple* items in the result: then you should include `item_id` in the result. Or we only get data for a *single* item: then you can further simplify the query.

Comment: All I need is a single item result.  This current query execution time is not in line with what I can use.  Note that the `item_change` table has 5.4M records.  Previous query runs in 32ms, while this one takes more than 80 seconds and still not completed.

Comment: That's a clear indication that something is going wrong. Adding many more rows will cost a bit, but not *that* much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Basic solution

Generate a complete list of months and `LEFT JOIN` the rest to it:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT to_char(m, 'YYYY-MON') AS yyyymmm
   FROM   generate_series(<start_date>, <end_date>, interval '1 month') m
   ) m
LEFT  JOIN ( <your query here> ) q USING (yyyymmm);
```

Related answers with more explanation:

- [Join a count query on a generate_series in postgres and also retrieve Null-values as "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413715/join-a-count-query-on-a-generate-series-in-postgres-and-also-retrieve-null-value/13414797#13414797)
- [Best way to count records by arbitrary time intervals in Rails+Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576794/best-way-to-count-records-by-arbitrary-time-intervals-in-railspostgres/15577413#15577413)

### Advanced solution for your case

Your query is more complicated than I first understood. You need the running sum over *all* rows of the selected item, then you want to trim rows older than a minimum date, and fill in missing months with the pre-calculated sum of the previous month.

I achieve this now with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.yearmonth, c.yearmonth)::date, sold_qty, on_hand
FROM  (
   SELECT yearmonth
        , COALESCE(sold_qty, 0) AS sold_qty
        , sum(on_hand_mon) OVER (ORDER BY yearmonth) AS on_hand
        , lead(yearmonth)  OVER (ORDER BY yearmonth)
                                - interval '1 month' AS nextmonth
   FROM (
      SELECT date_trunc('month', c.change_date) AS yearmonth
           , sum(c.sold_qty / s.qty)::numeric(18,2) AS sold_qty
           , sum(c.on_hand) AS on_hand_mon
      FROM   item_change      c         
      LEFT   JOIN item        i USING (item_id)
      LEFT   JOIN item_size   s ON s.item_id = i.item_id AND s.name = i.sell_size
      LEFT   JOIN item_plu    p ON p.item_id = i.item_id AND p.seq_num = 0
      WHERE  c.change_date < date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 day'
      AND    c.item_id = (SELECT item_id FROM item_plu WHERE number = '51515')
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) sub
   ) c
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL generate_series(c.yearmonth
                                  , c.nextmonth
                                  , interval '1 month') m(yearmonth) ON TRUE
WHERE  c.yearmonth > date_trunc('year', now()) - interval '540 days'
ORDER  BY COALESCE(m.yearmonth, c.yearmonth);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/00652/25) with a minimum test case.

#### Major points:

- I removed your VIEW from the query completely. Much cost for no gain.
- Since you select a ***single*** `item_id`, you don't need to `GROUP BY item_id` or `PARTITION BY item_id`.
- Use short table aliases and make all reference unambiguous - especially when posting in a public forum.
- Parentheses in your joins were just noise. Joins are executed left-to-right anyway by default.
- Simplified date bounds (since I operate with timestamps):

  ```
  date_trunc('year', current_date)  - interval '540 days'
  date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day'
  ```

  equivalent, but simpler & faster than:

  ```
  current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer - 540
  current_date - date_part('day',current_date)::integer
  ```
- I now fill in missing months after all calculations with `generate_series()` calls per row.
- It must be `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON TRUE`, not the short form of a `JOIN LATERAL` to catch the corner case of the last row. Detailed explanation:

  - [Find most common elements in array with a group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033312/find-most-common-elements-in-array-with-a-group-by/21033693#21033693)

#### Important side notes:

`character(22)` is a ***terrible*** data type for a primary key (or *any* column). Details:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Ideally this would be an `int` or `bigint` column, or possibly a [`UUID`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html).

Also, storing money amounts as [`money`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/postgresql-which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency/15729573#15729573) type or `integer`(representing Cents) performs much better overall.

**In the long run**, performance is bound to deteriorate, since you have to include all rows from the very beginning in your calculation. You should cut off old rows and materialize the balance of `on_hold` on a yearly basis or something.

Comment: I accepted the answer last week, but now I find out that it is not correct.  The running balance should keep what the previous record had if there's a month missing.  With the left join, and then added coalesce to the sums, I get 0's for the running balance, but that is incorrect.  Any suggestions, or should I rewrite the query, using the generate_series as the base?

Comment: @markdueck: I added an advanced solution. Basically rewrote your query to untangle it.

Comment: - Thank you VERY much for your help, but as mentioned above in previous comment, the time for this query takes too long, and it does not return with the correct starting running balance - meaning that it starts the running balance from the start date, not including sum of all previous on_hand.

I was thinking on changing to running something like this:
`select (select sum(sold_qty) from item_change ...) as sold_qty,
(select sum(on_hand) from item_change where clause .... ) as OH
from (series )`
-- where clause would include dates from the series.

Comment: @markdueck: I was fooled into thinking you actually wanted to return multiple `item_id` by your `GROUP BY item_id`. Also, I had a bug: the subselect can't be merged into the join condition that way. Added a largely simplified version with update explanation and fiddle.

Comment: HI again.  unfortunately the query above does not work because the date is limited too early, so the running balance is still wrong.  I adjusted the working query and placed it inside another select from which I limited the dates [here.](http://pastebin.com/mndfL8yH)  I'm not sure if I should change my original post to and include the right answer, or you want to do that? 

Thank you, Thank you.  your help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: in regards to the character varying(22) - unfortunately the database design is not by me and is not something I can change.   This is for an accounting system called Quasar by [Linux Canada Inc.](http://www.linuxcanada.com)

Comment: @markdueck: `character varying(22)` is already much better than `character(22)`. And: very tricky query! I added another solution and hope this solves it for good. Updated fiddle, too.