# Get count of created entries for each day

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

Let's say I have a this search query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), date(created_at)
FROM entries
WHERE date(created_at) >= date(current_date - interval '1 week')
GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

As you know then for example I get a result back like this:

```
count | date
  2   |  15.01.2014
  1   |  13.01.2014
  9   |  09.01.2014
```

But I do **not** get the days of the week where no entries where created.

How can I get a search result that looks like this, **including** the days where no entries where created?

```
count | date
  2   |  15.01.2014
  0   |  14.01.2014
  1   |  13.01.2014
  0   |  12.01.2014
  0   |  11.01.2014
  0   |  10.01.2014
  9   |  09.01.2014
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
SELECT day, COALESCE(ct, 0) AS ct
FROM  (SELECT now()::date - d AS day FROM generate_series (0, 6) d) d  -- 6, not 7
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT created_at::date AS day, count(*) AS ct 
   FROM   entries
   WHERE  created_at >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '6d'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) e USING (day);
```

Use a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression for your `WHERE` condition, so Postgres can use a plain index on `created_at`. Far more important for performance than all the rest.

To cover a week (including today), subtract 6 days from the start of "today", not 7.
Alternatively, shift the week by 1 to end "yesterday", as "today" is obviously incomplete, yet.

Assuming that `id` is defined `NOT NULL`, `count(*)` is identical to `count(id)`, but slightly faster. See:

- [Why is count(x.*) slower than count(*)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/309924/3684)

A [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) is not needed for the simple case. Would be slower and more verbose.

Aggregate first, join later. That's faster.

`now()` is Postgres' short syntax for the standard SQL [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) (which you can use as well). See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

This should be the shortest and fastest query. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Related:

- [Selecting sum and running balance for last 18 months with generate_series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670068/selecting-sum-and-running-balance-for-last-18-months-with-generate-series/27670540#27670540)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If it works I will mark it as correct but currently I get an error: FEHLER:  Unteranfrage in FROM muss Aliasnamen erhalten
ZEILE 2: FROM  (SELECT now::date - d AS day FROM generate_series (0, ...

Comment: I fixed it by using `current date` and giving a alias for the table! Thanks

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter, how is `count` with `*` faster than `count` on one column ? Doesn't the width of row enlarge when choosing `*` over one column in aggregate function?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Yes, the table alias was missing.

Comment: @ConsiderMe: When using `*` in `count(*)` it is not actually decomposed into whole rows, it just stands for the row itself: the mere existence of a row is enough to count, the actual value does not have to be inspected, That's a bit faster.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks, good to know. Some (in the past) did argue with me about the width of columns that need to be counted, thus leading to better performance using one column as a feed for aggregate function like `COUNT()`.

Comment: @ConsiderMe: Just run tests on any big table with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. The difference is small.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you're right. Tested with `*` and a `PK column`. There's a slight difference in favour of `*`. One more time, thank you.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter MAybe you can also help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371305/get-created-as-well-as-deleted-entries-of-last-week

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
with a as (select current_date - n as dt from generate_series(0, 6) as t(n)),
     b as (select count(id) cnt, date(created_at) created_at
           from entries
           where date(created_at) >= date(current_date - interval '1 week')
           group by date(created_at))
select coalesce(b.cnt,0), a.dt
from a
left join b on (a.dt = b.created_at)
order by a.dt;
```

`count` function will not generate 0 for non-existing rows. So you have to fill the rows for missing dates. With `generate_series` and simple date arithmetic, you can generate rows for dates of some period (in this case, 1 week). Then you can outer join to generate the final result. `coalesce` will substitute `null` to `0`.

Comment: Works! But is there nothing shorter?

Comment: You can drop COALESCE(), COUNT(column) doesn't count NULL values. COUNT(*) counts records and doesn't check for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell SQL to handle NULL. Return `0` if `NULL`

You can do this by `COALESCE`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: Thanks! But I dont understand It completly could you add a query please, specific to my question?

Comment: A date that isn't there, won't pop up using COALESCE. This just doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Use `generate_series()` to create the dates you need and JOIN to this list of dates:

```
SELECT  COUNT(id), 
    date(gdate)
FROM entries
    RIGHT JOIN generate_series(current_date - interval '1 week', current_date, '1 day') g(gdate) 
    ON date(created_at) = date(gdate) AND date(created_at) >= date(current_date - interval '1 week')
GROUP BY 
    date(gdate)
ORDER BY
    date(gdate) DESC;
```

Comment: @JohnSmith: What kind of errors/problems do you get? It must be something like this, but I didn't test it.

Comment: I get the same result as before!

Comment: The WHERE condition has to move to the JOIN condition. I replaced "current_date" with a fixed date, my laptop is already using March....

Comment: Oh this one is excellent! I would rate it as correct answer if you correct your query to use current_date! Thank you!