# Get daily count of rows for a range of days

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My database table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE record (
    id                  int,
    status              int,
    created_at          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And I want to create a generic query to get count of `record` created on every single day in given period period of time(30 days , 1 week , 3 days etc).

**For EXAMPLE**,  I want to know in last 30 days on every single day how many records are created.

**Expected Output if duration is 3 days**:

```
Number of day  : issue count
day1 :           2    
day2 :           3
day3 :           3
```

#### What I have so far:

With a little help from stackoverflow I am able to create a query to calculate the count for a single day. To get this for whole week or month, I would need to run this query for every single day separately?

```
select COUNT(id)
from record
where extract(isodow from created_at) = 1
and created_at >= current_date - 7;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end `group by date(created_at)`

As pointed out in the comments, `- 7` here will get you the last 7 days.  That number should be adjusted to fit your specific needs.

```
select date(created_at) as day, COUNT(1)
from record
where created_at >= current_date - 7
group by date(created_at)
```

You could also modify the where clause to get a specific date range.  That would look like so

```
where date(created_at) between '2021-03-31' and '2021-04-01'
```

Comment: Sir I didn't get . seems answer is not formatted

Comment: And spell it out that `-7` will get last 7 days.  Calendar week or month will require more code. OK?

Comment: getting this   pq: syntax error at or near "and"

Comment: there is no "and" in the code provided, have you added something to that code?

Comment: @Ninja Not sure how long this fiddle will be valid for so just adding in the comments, but here is a working example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6649a1/2

Answer (score 1):

Create days of interest in your time range with `generate_series()`. Then `LEFT JOIN` and aggregate.
Example period: March 2021:

```sql
SELECT the_day::date, count(r.created_at) AS issue_count
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2021-03-01' -- start of range (inclusive)
                     , timestamp '2021-04-01' -- end of range (exclusive)
                     , interval  '1 day') the_day
LEFT   JOIN record r ON created_at >= the_day
                    AND created_at <  the_day + interval '1 day'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

This way the results includes days with 0 rows.
The join condition allows the use of an index on `(created_at)`, it's "sargable" - as opposed to something like `WHERE date(created_at) BETWEEN _start AND _end'`.

For **bigger date-ranges / many rows** it will be faster to select and aggregate the whole range from the table before the join. Like:

```sql
WITH input AS (
   SELECT timestamp '2021-03-01' AS _start  -- inlusive
        , timestamp '2021-04-01' AS _end    -- exclusive
   )
SELECT the_day, COALESCE(r.issue_count, 0) AS issue_count
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(_start, _end, interval '1 day')::date AS the_day
   FROM   input
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT created_at::date AS the_day, count(*) AS issue_count
   FROM   input i
   JOIN   record r ON r.created_at >= i._start
                  AND r.created_at <  i._end
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) r USING (the_day);
```

Alternatively, drop the CTE `input` and provide `_start` and `_end` as query parameters directly.

See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)
- [Get count of created entries for each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362384/get-count-of-created-entries-for-each-day/29363479#29363479)
- [Efficient subquery for aggregate time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493538/efficient-subquery-for-aggregate-time-series/42494032#42494032)

Comment: Hi. I think here should be something like:   
`SELECT the_day::date
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2021-03-01 0:0:1' -- start of range (inclusive)
                     , timestamp '2021-04-01' -- end of range (exclusive)
                     , interval  '1 day') the_day;` otherwise it will produce date '2021-04-01'.