# How to get the Date difference between two dates in postgresql? excluding weekends and only office hours

Tags: postgresql, time, difference

How to get the Date difference between two dates in postgresql? ( Excluding weekends Saturday and Sunday, and out of office hours). It should calculate the time only on weekdays during office hours( 9 - 6). My requirement is to calculate the time between 2 date columns in hours. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide your attempts?

Comment: I am using postgresql version 8.2 I have gone through the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839319/calculate-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-postgresql but the generate series function throws an error.                                                                  ERROR:  function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, interval) does not exist
LINE 3:    SELECT t_id, generate_series (t_start
                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.