# How to count days except Sundays between two dates in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, date-arithmetic

To find the number of days between two dates we can use something like this:

```
SELECT date_part('day',age('2017-01-31','2017-01-01')) as total_days;
```

In the above query we got 30 as output instead of 31. Why is that?
And I also want to find the number of days *except* Sundays. Expected output for the interval `('2017-01-01', '2017-01-31')`:

```
Total Days = 31
Total Days except Sundays = 26
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `date_part('day',age('2017-01-31','2017-01-01'))` gives you a wrong result if the "age" is more then a month. e.g. `date_part('day', age('2016-02-28','2016-01-01'))` would return 27 although it should be 58. If you want the number of days between two dates, just subtract them: `date '2017-01-31' - date '2017-01-01'`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name... will use this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define *"between two dates"* more closely. Lower and upper bound included or excluded? A common definition would be to ***include*** the lower and ***exclude*** the upper bound of an interval. Plus, define the result as 0 when lower and upper bound are identical. This definition happens to coincide with date subtraction *exactly*.

```
SELECT date '2017-01-31' - date '2017-01-01' AS days_between
```

This exact definition is important for excluding Sundays. For the given definition an interval from Sun - Sun (1 week later) does not include the upper bound, so there is only *1* Sunday to subtract.

```
interval in days  | sundays
0                 | 0
1-6               | 0 or 1
7                 | 1
8-13              | 1 or 2
14                | 2
...
```

An interval of 7 days always includes exactly one Sunday.

We can get the minimum result with a plain integer division (*days / 7*), which truncates the result.

The extra Sunday for the remainder of 1 - 6 days depends on the first day of the interval. If it's a Sunday, bingo; if it's a Monday, too bad. Etc. We can derive a simple formula from this:

```
SELECT days, sundays, days - sundays AS days_without_sundays
FROM  (
   SELECT z - a AS days
      , ((z - a) + EXTRACT(isodow FROM a)::int - 1 ) / 7 AS sundays
   FROM  (SELECT date '2017-01-02' AS a       -- your interval here
               , date '2017-01-30' AS z) tbl
   ) sub;
```

Works for *any* given interval.
Note: [`isodow`, not `dow` for `EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

To ***include*** the upper bound, just replace `z - a` with `(z - a) + 1`. (Would work without parentheses, due to operator precedence, but better be clear.)

Performance characteristic is ***O(1)*** (constant) as opposed to a conditional aggregate over a generated set with *O(N)*.

Related:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)
- [Calculate working hours between 2 dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839319/calculate-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-postgresql/17282639#17282639)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `generate_series` to generate all the dates between given date and then take count of required days.

```
SELECT
    count(case when extract(dow from generate_series) <> 0 then 1 end) n
from generate_series('2017-01-01'::date,'2017-01-31'::date, '1 day');
```