# Counting number of weekdays between two dates

Tags: postgresql, time-series, plpgsql

I am trying to get the number of weekdays between two dates in plpgsql. The following is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION weekdays(DATE, DATE) RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    d date := $1;
    weekdays integer := 0
BEGIN

LOOP
    IF select extract(dow from date d) != 6 or select extract(dow from date d) != 0
      weekdays := weekdays +1
    END IF
    d := d + 1;
    EXIT WHEN d > $2;
END LOOP;
RETURN weekdays;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> Unterminated dollar quote started at position 56 in SQL
> CREATE FUNCTION weekdays(DATE, DATE) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$ DECLARE d date := $1.
> Expected terminating $$
> ```

Comment: I don't get that error message.

Comment: it seems to be mostly a matter of arithmetic, there;s should be no need to count them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is due to a missing `;` after `weekdays integer := 0;`. Plus several more errors of this kind. This would *work*:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION weekdays(date, date)
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
   d        date := $1;
   weekdays int  := 0;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      IF extract(isodow from d) < 6 THEN  -- simpler
         weekdays := weekdays + 1;
      END IF;
      d := d + 1;
      EXIT WHEN d > $2;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN weekdays;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

But I suggest this ***simpler and faster SQL function*** instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weekdays_sql(date, date)
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
SELECT count(*)::int
FROM   generate_series($1, $2, interval '1d') d
WHERE  extract(isodow FROM d) < 6;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Further performance improvement for big ranges possible. Related:

- [How to count days except Sundays between two dates in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877136/how-to-count-days-except-sundays-between-two-dates-in-postgres/41878981#41878981)
- [Calculate working hours between 2 dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839319/calculate-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-postgresql/17282639#17282639)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop, or generate a temporary resultset with generate_series(), the answer can be found using only arithmetic.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.weekdays(s date, e date) RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
DECLARE
  sd int = extract (isodow from s-1); 
  ed int = extract (isodow from e); 
BEGIN
   RETURN - case sd when 7 then 5 when 6 then 5 else sd end 
          + case ed when 7 then 5 when 6 then 5 else ed end 
          + (e-ed-s+sd+1)/7*5;
END;
$function$;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks less complex to me and is also working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weekdays
(
date1 DATE,
date2 DATE
)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE weekdays INTEGER;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(extract(ISODOW FROM series)) INTO weekdays
FROM generate_series(date1::date, date2::date, '1 day'::interval) series
WHERE extract(ISODOW FROM series) < 6;

RETURN weekdays;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```